# Rundeck from docker: no logs?

Tags: rundeck

Running rundeck from docker (default backend), but noticed there are no logs. This documentation seems not complete / not valid for docker deployment: https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/maintenance/logs.html

All the logs inside docker:/home/rundeck/server/logs have 0 size.

How to review the logs when running as a docker ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The execution logs are stored at the `/home/rundeck/var/logs/rundeck` path, so, a good idea is to mount it as a volume (to see them in your local filesystem), take a look at this `docker-compose` example:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
    rundeck:
        image: rundeck/rundeck:4.2.1
        environment:
            RUNDECK_GRAILS_URL: http://localhost:4440
            RUNDECK_DATABASE_DRIVER: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
            RUNDECK_DATABASE_USERNAME: rundeck
            RUNDECK_DATABASE_PASSWORD: rundeck
            RUNDECK_DATABASE_URL: jdbc:mariadb://mysql/rundeck?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true 
            RUNDECK_LOGGING_STRATEGY: FILE
        volumes:
          - ./data/logs/:/home/rundeck/var/logs/rundeck/
        ports:
          - 4440:4440
        tty: true
    mysql:
        image: mysql:8
        expose:
          - 3306
        environment:
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
          - MYSQL_DATABASE=rundeck
          - MYSQL_USER=rundeck
          - MYSQL_PASSWORD=rundeck
```

The `service.log` is available in the [docker logs command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/), to see it just do  `docker logs <container_id> -f`.